# How is TCP sequence number stored?

Tags: tcp, numbers, sequence, seq

As we can see in the image the seq number of the TCP layer of a packet captured by wireshark is `45943` in decimal, and it's represented by the hex digits `61a08950`. Obviously the direct translation of that hex number to decimal is not equivalen to `45943`, so how is this number stored?, it is encoded or something like that?

[image: TCP Sequence number]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. They stored in big endian format.
2. Wireshark shows relative sequence numbers, not the absolute numbers.

Here is how to configure Wireshark to show the absolute numbers:

https://wiki.wireshark.org/TCP_Relative_Sequence_Numbers